# Prevent Mac app from being downloaded on Yosemite

Tags: macos, app-store, osx-yosemite, mac-app-store

I have a free app in the Apple App store that apparently is not compatible with something in Yosemite. I plan to resolve the bugs once I have some more free time away from work.  As a short term solution - does anyone know of way to change the compatibility settings of app in the Apple App Store without submitting new binaries?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Though it doesn't exactly describe your situation, I'd think you might have issue with this section of The [Mac App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/mac/):

> 2.25 Apps that do not run on the currently shipping OS will be rejected